# Clojure tools.trace woes

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure

im hoping you guys could help me out. Im trying to use the trace features found in https://github.com/clojure/tools.trace

i have downloaded the git and have copied over the files into my src folder in my clojure project in intellij

The problem im having is that i dont know how to import the tools.trace tool into my current project for use.  I have tried loading the individual macros into my repl and them executing against my work but it cannot find the tools.

Can someone tell me how i import tools like this into intellij for clojure???
I have checked the readme but nothing in there on how to install.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A great way to use clojure is in combination with leiningen.

http://leiningen.org/

It's a build/test/dependency tool for clojure, and in fact the standard way to setup a clojure project.

Your dependencies than just go in one file, like this :

```
    (defproject leiningen.org "1.0.0"
  :description "Generate static HTML for http://leiningen.org"
  :dependencies [ [org.clojure/tools.trace "0.7.9"]                             
 ]      
 :main leiningen.web)
```

Answer (score 1):

> i have downloaded the git and have copied over the files into my src folder in my clojure project in intellij

Instead of manually trying to put files where you want them, use a dependency manager like [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). This is pretty standard when working with Clojure.

> I have checked the readme but nothing in there on how to install.

Ah, [but there is](https://github.com/clojure/tools.trace#releases-and-dependency-information):

> [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) dependency information:
>
> ```
> [org.clojure/tools.trace "0.7.9"]
> ```
>
> [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) dependency information:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
>   <artifactId>tools.trace</artifactId>
>   <version>0.7.8</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Put one of these into the appropriate file (e.g. `project.clj` for Leiningen) and tell the tool to install your dependencies (e.g. by running `lein deps`).

You'll probably want to read the appropriate documentation. Maybe start with [this Leiningen tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md).